# Qt QGraphicsScene copy

Tags: c++, qt

I have a QGraphicsScene that I want to copy and append to the start of a list.  What is the best method of doing this?

```
QGraphicsScene* m_scene = new QGraphicsScene();
QGraphicsScene* m_DuplicateScene;

QList<QGraphicsScene *>m_list;
```

Comment: Append to the list, or insert at the beginning of the list (sometimes called prepend)?  Also, do you just want to copy the pointer, or the whole scene?

Comment: I want to copy the whole scene, and append it to the list.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Doing this would be very complicated because you don't know anything about the children of `m_scene`.  Even if you `dynamic_cast` and create a `clone()` function for each type of `QGraphicsItem`, you still need to remember that other people can subclass `QGraphicsItem` and create their own type of graphics item, making them unclonable by you.

Basically, no, you can't duplicate a `QGraphicsScene` (cloning all items in the process).  You can't even make references to the children of the original scene's children because a `QGraphicsItem` can only have one scene.

Unless I'm missing a method call, of course.  Searches for "clone," "copy," and "duplicate" produced no results, though.

On your second question, use `QList<T *>::push_front`.  Thus, `m_list.push_front`(`m_DuplicateScene`);

(Side note: you prepend to the start of a list, and append to the end of a list.)

Comment: Thank you, I ended up created a method that serialised the Scenes properties and then iterated through the Scenes objects and got them to serialised themselves as well.
Its slow and a lot of work but it works.

Answer (score 2):

I make a copy of QGraphicsScene's items in my project. I'm using this way. may be helpful.
I have a class like this:

```
class DiagramScene : public QGraphicsScene
{
[some datas]
}
```

and another class in this like:

```
class DiagramItem : public QGraphicsItem
{
}
```

and in copy function, I use a code like this:

```
Diagram_Scene myScene;

foreach (QGraphicsItem *item, diagram_scene1->items()) 
{
    if(item->type() == DiagramItem::Type)
    {
        DiagramItem *di = qgraphicsitem_cast<DiagramItem*>(item);
        myScene.addItem(di);
    }
}
```